# Find General Applications on Linux

Tags: linux, netbeans

I am new to Linux Platform. I have been given access to a server machine running on Linux ( but I don't know which Linux Platform it is running). I have been told that netbeans is installed on the machine. But, I find problem in searching the exact location where i open a framework window.

Any suggestion please.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always try

```
sudo locate netbeans
```

or

```
sudo find / -name netbeans
```

(Or without the `sudo` if you don't have the permissions.)

Comment: Any other commnds please because i don;t have sudo autorization in server machine